# Martingale and local martingales

Tags: brownian-motion, martingales, stochastic-integrals, local-martingales

I have to show that $e^{B_t^1}\cos(B_t^2)$ is a martingale ($B=(B^1,B^2)$ is a two-dimensional Brownian Motion). I used Ito's formula and got
$e^{B_t^1}\cos(B_t^2)=1+\int_0^t e^{B_s^1}\cos(B_s^2)dB_s^1-\int_0^t e^{B_s^1}\sin(B_t^2)dBs^2$. From the right side I know that these are local martingales, but are they martingales, and how can I show that? Do I have to show that it is bounded? Please help me!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply Ito's formula for:
$$
f(x_1,x_2)=e^{x_1}\cos(x_2)
$$
$$
f_{x_1}(x_1,x_2)=e^{x_1}\cos(x_2)\quad f_{x_2}(x_1,x_2)=-e^{x_1}\sin(x_2)
$$
$$
f_{x_1x_1}(x_1,x_2)=e^{x_1}\cos(x_2)\quad f_{x_1x_2}(x_1,x_2)=-e^{x_1}\sin(x_2)
$$
$$
f_{x_2x_2}(x_1,x_2)=e^{x_1}\cos(x_2)
$$
Then:
$$
\mathrm{d}f(B_1,B_2)=f_{x_1}(B_1,B_2)\mathrm{d}B_1+f_{x_2}(B_1,B_2)\mathrm{d}B_2+
$$
$$
+\frac{f_{x_1x_1}(B_1,B_2)+2{f_{x_1x_2}(B_1,B_2)}+{f_{x_2x_2}(B_1,B_2)}{}}{2}=...
$$

Comment: but how do I know that this is a real martingale?

Comment: $\mathbb{E}(|e^{B_1(t)}\cos(B_2(t))|)\leq\mathbb{E}e^{B_1(t)}$. Since $B_1(t)$ has distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,\sqrt{t})$, this is the moment generating function of a normal at $u=1$, and since $\mathbb{E}(e^{uX})=\exp({u\mu+u^2\sigma^2/2})$.

Comment: do you know the theorem or a link?

Comment: http://www.le.ac.uk/users/dsgp1/COURSES/MATHSTAT/6normgf.pdf

Comment: i meant something like if $\mathbb{E}[|X_t|]<\infty$ a local martingale is a martingale. Thanks for the rest. :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be $
f_{x_2x_2}(x_1,x_2)=-e^{x_1}\cos(x_2)
$
and
$$
\ldots+\frac{f_{x_1x_1}(B_1,B_2)(dB_1)^2+2 f_{x_1x_2}(B_1,B_2) dB_1dB_2+f_{x_2x_2}(B_1,B_2)(dB_2)^2}{2}=... ?
$$

Comment: Correct, I accidentally left those out. Thanks! :)